# Probability of picking something the same

Tags: probability

A drawer contains two white socks, three blue socks and two red
socks. Two socks are drawn at random – what is the probability
that they are the same colour?

Is the answer 5/21?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct:$$\frac{{2\choose 2}+{3\choose 2}+{2\choose 2}}{{7\choose 2}}=\frac{5}{21}$$